# R plotly dynamic line width

Tags: r, plotly

I have multiple paths in my data, separated by NAs to build separated bar data, for which I'm trying to implement dynamic widths based on another value in that observation (column `z` below).

Reproducible Example:

```
  index <- c(1,1,NA,2,2)
  value <- c(50,51,NA,51,52)
  width <- c(3,3,NA,5,5)
  data <- data.frame(x = index,
                 y = value,
                 z = width)

  p <- plot_ly(data, x = x, y = y, mode = "lines", 
           marker = list(color = '#ff2626'),
           line = list(width = data$z))
```

Where I am trying to reference column `z` for the `line = list(width = data$z)` paramter.

Can this be done in the Plotly for R package, or does the line width need to be fixed?

Comment: [This github  request](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/147) suggests it not possible in the JS version, does this also mean it's not possible in R?

Comment: A sub-prime solution will be to create a separate trace for each width, as I only have 3 different width categories (narrow(1), medium(3), wide(5)). However, this would become an issue if you had more potential width options. Also, it's not great should you wish to change the width categories later on.

Answer (score 1):

```
index <- c(1,1,NA,2,2)
value <- c(50,51,NA,51,52)
width <- c(3,3,NA,5,5)
data <- data.frame(x = index, y = value, z = width)

# first, create an empty plotly object
p <- plot_ly(type = "scatter", mode = "lines+markers", marker = list(color = '#ff2626'))

# second, every third line a new lines definition begins. Loop through lines in steps of 3 and add lines
for (i in seq(1, nrow(data), by = 3)){
  p <- p %>% add_trace(x=data[i,"x"], y=data[i:(i+1), "y"], line=list(width=data[i,"z"]))
}
```

[image]

Comment: Agreed this is a neater solution than the one I suggested above. But I am wondering if there is a way to achieve this built into Plotly. Ideally, I'd like to avoid the loop as I'll be dealing with a large amount of observations.